# EntityFramework DbSet.Attach() + OData QueryInterceptor

Tags: entity-framework, odata

I have OData service with QueryInterceptor, which I suppose to attach a record to current DBSet - shouldn't newly attached record be available immidiately in data context?

```
[QueryInterceptor("MyTable")]
public Expression<Func<MyTable, bool>> FilterMyTable()
{
    this.CurrentDataSource.MyTable.Attach(new MyTable()
    {
        PK = "1"
    });

    return p => p.PK == "1";
}
```

new MyTable entity is not available in this handler's this.CurrentDataSource.MyTable,
and it is not returned by OData webservice either.

Only way that works - use 'Add' instead of 'Attach', save changes to db, then webservice returns record from db.
Can webservice return such new record without saving it to db first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MyTable will be available from the Datacontext - you do not need to Attach. This should work:

```
[QueryInterceptor("MyTable")]
public Expression<Func<MyTable, bool>> FilterMyTable()
{
    return p => p.PK == "1";
}
```